# Lamé parameters of granite and similar rocks

Tags: rocks

I am looking for a book or an article where I can find the Lamé parameters of Granite, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help, [*Lamé parameters of common rocks in the Earth's crust and upper mantle*](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1029/2009JB007134)?